# Javascript - Keep the original image after dropping it in another container

Tags: javascript, html

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
</script>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<img id="x" src="X.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75" />
```

I want to drag the `x.png` file and drop it into the div, but `x.png` will move into the div if I do so. How can I achieve that, after I drag and drop, the div gets a `x.png`, and the original `x.png` is still where it was?

Answer (score 10):

You can do that by duplicating the required DOM element by using cloneNode(true) method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
 }
function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
ev.preventDefault();
}
</script>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<img id="x" src="X.png" draggable="true" 
    ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I will stick to the example shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

*Assuming we have this document:*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    <!-- script comes in the text below -->
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)"
  ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

  <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"
  ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

 </body>
</html>
```

**Normal Drag & Drop**

Normal drag and drop has such functions assigned to the respective elements:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

**Drag & Copy**

Whereas you'll have to alter the drop function so that it copies the DOM element instead of moving it.

```
//other functions stay the same

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

Try this page: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop
And then append a `.cloneNode(true)` to `getElementById(data)`.

You could even do things like in file managers: Ctrl-Key switches from moving to copying:

```
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  if (ev.ctrlKey)
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
  else
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```